# Image overlay for Windows Phone 8 maps

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps

In Windows phone 8 is possible to add UIElements at specific GeoLocation using MapOverlay. Or draw a polygon which will be resizable according to zoom level with MapPolygon. But I can specify only fill color for such polygon. I need to draw an image overlay at a specific GeoLocation boundaries, and resize it the same way MapPolygon does. Is there are any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:** Found this question [How to create auto-scalling image lying on WP8 maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797456/how-to-create-auto-scalling-image-lying-on-wp8-maps?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create auto-scalling image lying on WP8 maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797456/how-to-create-auto-scalling-image-lying-on-wp8-maps)